# The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file

Tags: ee2

Hi can you help? im going to upload some mp3 but doesnt work that problem can you help in EE2, where can find the solution ?thank you

Comment: Sounds like a server configuration issue, but without more details of what you're trying to achieve, it would be difficult to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You might be best contacting your ISP to check with them what the maximum allowed file upload size is. You should also be able to check via the PHP info screen 'within' EE2 by navigating to:

Tools > Utilities > PHP Info

Then search for "upload_max_filesize" - if the figure there is lower than the file size of your MP3 then you will need to raise the maximum file size allowed by the server - again this is something your ISP should be able to help you with. :)

Answer (score 0):

Per the error message:

> The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file

So you need to increase the maximum upload size in your PHP configuration file. If you don't have access to this, ask your web host.